# how to retrieve namespace of an xml using xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xml-namespaces

### XML:

```
<Report xmlns="https://defaultnamespace/abc">     
<Conversion>
<Type>FirstElement</Type>
</Conversion>
<Conversion>
<Type>SecondElement</Type>
</Conversion>
<Conversion>
<Type>ThirdElement</Type>
</Conversion>
<Last>This is last element</Last>
</Report>
```

### XSLT:

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:cs="https://defaultnamespace/abc">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="/cs:Report/cs:Conversion/cs:Type">
<xsl:element name="Converting"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:element name="LastOne"><xsl:value-of select="/cs:Report/cs:Last"/>                  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above XSLT fails when the input XML has a different namespace. So, I need an XSLT that will dynamically get the namespace from input XML and does the transformation. Please suggest me the right solution.

Need further clarification in the requirement pls comment. Thanks in advance.

With Regards, Mani.

Comment: Is there a list of known namespaces that the input XML can have? -- P.S. It seems very strange that the namespace would change, but not the structure. -- P.P.S That's not a valid stylesheet.

Comment: @michael.hor257k
Yess michael, we have a scenario that the input XML may have one namespace of these two namespaces(1.https://defaultnamespace/abc , 2.https://defaultnamespace1/abc ).And the structure of the XML is same. I have modified XSLT. Please help me now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the following

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cs1="https://defaultnamespace/abc" xmlns:cs2="https://defaultnamespace1/abc" exclude-result-prefixes="cs1 cs2">
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cs1:Report">
    <xsl:for-each select="cs1:Conversion/cs1:Type">
      <xsl:element name="Converting">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:element name="LastOne">
      <xsl:value-of select="cs1:Last"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cs2:Report">
    <xsl:for-each select="cs2:Conversion/cs2:Type">
      <xsl:element name="Converting">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:element name="LastOne">
      <xsl:value-of select="cs2:Last"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some options, you can use a wildcard

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="/*:Report/*:Conversion/*:Type">
<xsl:element name="Converting"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:element name="LastOne"><xsl:value-of select="/*:Report/*:Last"/>                  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or you can simply declare two namespaces

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:pf1="http://example.com/ns1" xmlns:pf2="http://example.com/ns2">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="/pf1:Report/pf1:Conversion/pf1:Type | /pf2:Report/pf2:Conversion/pf2:Type">
<xsl:element name="Converting"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:element name="LastOne"><xsl:value-of select="/pf1:Report/pf1:Last | /pf2:Report/pf2:Last"/>                  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution when you want a stylesheet to operate on source XML in two (or more) /different namespaces is to run a pipeline that first transforms the XML into a single "normalized" namespace and then does the transformation work proper. The normalization phase, assuming it doesn't have to make any changes to the content, can be done something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="node()">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://normalized.namespace/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```